# Laravel livewire, unable to locate component in subfolder

Tags: laravel, subdirectory, laravel-livewire

Folder structure:

```
Livewire
- Things
    - Addthing.php
```

Blade file

```
 @livewire('things.addthing')
```

is unable to locate it: `Unable to find component: [things.addthing]`

Without subdirectory, this works fine as:

```
Livewire
- Addthing.php
```

.

```
 @livewire('addthing')
```

How do I get Livewire components to work in a subdirectory?

Comment: Check Here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745082/a-livewire-component-was-not-found-after-creating-a-component-in-a-custom-path/64750482#64750482

Answer (score 5):

It should work like this, did you also update your namespace to match the path?

For example:

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Things;
```

Comment: I previously copied a whole component code into another (different directory/level). I had to change the namespace otherwise component cannot be found. Tyvm

Answer (score 2):

Know this is an old question, but adding this here as ran into the same issue and it could help someone.

The issue I had was with the name spacing, so for example the namespace was:-

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\SomeThing
```

Notice the capitalised T for Thing, so when we do this in the namespace we have to use an hyphen in the blade template to reference the space, so:-

```
@livewire('some-thing.component')
```

and same if we want to emit an event to this component:-

```
$emitTo('some-thing.component', 'event')
```

Simple thing but tripped me up

Comment: Thanks for this @ColinMD, I had a similar issue, locally livewire would be fine, but in prod my component `<livewire:components.faqs></livewire:components.faqs>` would not be found. The class was `class FAQs` so the component needed to become `<livewire:components.f-a-qs></livewire:components.f-a-qs>`

Answer (score 0):

I referenced it as @livewire('things.addthings') in the blade and it worked maybe check your typo.